# What happens to the assumption ∂p/∂y≈0 in the region of separated boundary layer? is it still valid?

Tags: aerodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I am reading about Boundary Layer(BL) and seems that in the derivation of the governing equations there is an assumption that the pressure, $p$, in $y$ direction is constant, that is:

$${\partial p \over \partial y} \approx 0$$

regardless of the $x$ location.
However, I am already wondering how valid is this assumption when the boundary layer separates.

Is that assumption valid for both Laminar BL and Turbulent BL?

Comment: It's possible to derive the condition you mention from the Navier Stokes equations (for example [here](https://web.mit.edu/fluids-modules/www/highspeed_flows/ver2/bl_Chap2.pdf)). which assumptions are needed to get to this point?

Comment: I am not sure but this won't be valid because pressure changes in separated flow